# Input Checkbox checked by default

Tags: html, css

For the life of me I cant set my CheckBox to checked at page load. 
I have tried adding `value="true"` and `Checked="checked"`  after id and still nothing. Any ideas?

```
<div class="onoffswitch-container">
<span class="onoffswitch-title">Open Inline</span>
<span class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline"> 
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="inline">
<span class="onoffswitch-inner" data-swchoff-text="OFF" data-swchon-text="ON"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the `checked` attribute like this `<input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" checked id="inline">`

Comment: `checked="checked"` was correct. Shorter variant is just `checked`.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

just write "checked" and it works

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline" checked>
```

Answer (score 22):

added "true" parameter below, just try it before, and it works for me

```
<input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline" checked="true">
```

Comment: This works wonders if you have a styled checkbox where the true input is hidden. Thanks!

Comment: using "true" might be misleading. because you can't set the value to "false" and get the opposite result. only the attribute being there is important. not the value and people tend to set `checked=""` if it needs to have xml syntax.

Answer (score 8):

The attribute `checked="checked"` does work and the shorthand notation is just `checked`.

```html
<div class="onoffswitch-container">
<span class="onoffswitch-title">Open Inline</span>
<span class="onoffswitch">
<input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="inline" checked="checked"/> 
<label class="onoffswitch-label" for="inline">
<span class="onoffswitch-inner" data-swchoff-text="OFF" data-swchon-text="ON"></span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm partial to the more explainy quality of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all above solutions and nothing worked. It did give me some terminology to continue my research. What I ended up doing was going to the bottom of the code and added `$('#inline').prop('checked', true);`
This solved my problem.

Comment: Echoing that this was what worked for me. The checked attribute pre-set in HTML does not work for some reason.

Comment: jquery for life. It's funny, some approaches will essentially be, never use jquery, unless you want to make sure something works.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `checked` content attribute. Here's the relevant snippet from the official documentation: ([Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-checked)):

> The checked content attribute is a boolean attribute that gives the default checkedness of the input element. When the checked content attribute is added, if the control does not have dirty checkedness, the user agent must set the checkedness of the element to true; when the checked content attribute is removed, if the control does not have dirty checkedness, the user agent must set the checkedness of the element to false.

Note the docs have links to definition of relevant terms.

If it seems too technical, you can always go to [MDN page on `checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked). MDN contributors have put up considerable effort into "translating" HTML Standard into more readable/understandable form (often times with examples), especially useful to people without a solid foundation on web related terminology and concepts.

**Note:** You'll also find the [direct answer to your question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#Checking_boxes_by_default) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="checkbox" checked />
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's worth adding that setting the `checked` attribute will check the box and not allow it to be unchecked by the user.  If the desired functionality is for the checkbox to be checked by default but still able to be unchecked by the user, use the `defaultChecked` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="inline" defaultChecked />
```

or

```
document.getElementById("inline").defaultChecked = true;
```