# ASP.NET Checkbox not setting bool value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

First of all, thank you for your help. I'm pretty new.

This should be super simple but I've spent hours trying to figure this out. I have a form in my view. The form is populating everything correctly - except for the checkbox. I've researched and researched and tried a lot of different suggestions online. No matter what I try, the form sets the same value for checked and unchecked.

View:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
         <input id="lunch45" type="checkbox" value="true">45 minute lunch
    </label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Lunchsubmit-form").click(function () {
            var model = {};
            model.EmployeeID = Number($("#lunchemployeeId").val());
            model.LunchTime = Date($('#lunchtimeId').val());
            model.PositionID = Number($("#lunchposition").val());
            model.LongerLunch = Boolean($('#lunch45').val());
            console.log("model", model);
            $.ajax({
                type: "HttpPost",
                url: "/Home/CreateLunch",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success)
                        window.location.href = "/Home/Index";
                    else
                        alert("Error: Lunch not submitted");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Error: Lunch not submitted");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Model:

```
public class Lunch
{
    public int LunchID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime LunchTime { get; set; }
    public int? PositionID { get; set; }
    public bool LongerLunch { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks again. I know how simple this should be but nothing's working.

Comment: <input id="lunch45"   checked="checked" ... >  or simple <input id="lunch45" checked ... >  . Then the value can take any string or number you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input Checkbox checked by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743629/input-checkbox-checked-by-default)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I've tried that... I think there must be something else buggy in the code. All of those suggestions keep returning the same value. I updated it to this: <label><input type="checkbox" id="lunch45" checked value="true">45 minute lunch</label> and it returns true both ways..... I've tried to change true to false in the value - also tried to leave the value blank. Returns the same value both ways.

Comment: Try using 1 and 0 ,  false is not equal to 'false' Check this about Boolean function https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-boolean/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 1 and 0 , read about JS Boolean function [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-boolean/)

Check

```
alert(Boolean(Number("0")));
alert(Boolean(Number("1")));
```

Then

```
  <input id="lunch45" type="checkbox" value="0" />
  ...
  model.LongerLunch = Boolean(Number($('#lunch45').val()));
```

Or use checkbox directly

```
model.LongerLunch = $('#lunch45').is(":checked");
```

Or maybe you need verify is checked, before get the value

```
<input id="lunch45" type="checkbox" value="0" >
<input id="lunchx" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>

alert($('#lunch45').is(":checked"));
alert($('#lunchx').is(":checked"));
```

Comment: You are a genius! <input id="lunch45" type="checkbox" value="0" /> and model.LongerLunch = $('#lunch45').is(":checked"); worked great. I did have to change value="0" to value="" to make it save correctly to the database. But it worked great otherwise. Thank you!!!!